# Format number that comes with leading zeroes correctly

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I need to import to my database a csv file generated by my bank, I'm working with Laravel 5.6 and Laravel-Excel to read the file, the thing is that the amount field comes in a weird format and I do not know how to import that correctly to my db. According to the bank the field format is numeric(18,2) but the amount field comes with a lot of leading zeroes and not a decimal separator:

This is the real amount `700.00` and this is what it comes in the csv file `000000000000070000`

Is there a way to manage or correctly format that number? The bank only exports data in that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide all the amounts to 100 and the result will become the "normal" form. Also all leading zeroes will be eliminated.

Comment: Be *very* cautious about converting currency to floating point types. If it's not critical in your application then fine, but be aware of the issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency

Comment: @TravisBritz `mysql` has a numeric type `DECIMAL` intended for currency values and I suppose that Douglas is aware of difference between `DECIMAL` and `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE`.

Comment: @Kondybas thank you, that is a useful point for someone using MySQL.

Comment: @TravisBritz yes, my DB has decimal fields, I'm aware of the difference between those fields.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you are storing monetary values. If you are storing them as decimals the do as @Kondybas suggests. Otherwise, you may consider storing them as their whole, lowest-denomination values; i.e. in cents/pence.